# How can I make the ordering of constructors more efficient?

Tags: java, constructor, coding-efficiency

I am currently working on a program that has to have every possible example of calculations. I made a class for number, difference, product, modulus, quotient, and sum. I am doing something like this

```
Difference(Number first_number,Number second_number){
    s1 = first_number + second_number;
}
Difference(Number first_number, Product first_difference){
    s1 = first_number + first_difference
}
Difference(Product first_difference, Number first_number){
    s1 = first_product + first_number;
}
Difference(Product first_difference, Product second_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + second_difference;
}
Difference(Number first_number, Quotient first_difference){
    s1 = first_number + first_difference;
}
Difference(Quotient first_difference, Number first_number){
    s1 = first_difference + first_number;
}
Difference(Quotient first_difference, Quotient second_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + second_difference;
}
Difference(Number first_number, Difference first_difference){
    s1 = first_number + first_difference;
}
Difference(Difference first_difference, Number first_number){
    s1 = first_number + first_difference;
}
Difference(Difference first_difference, Difference second_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + second_difference;
}
Difference(Number first_number, Sum first_Difference){
    s1 = first_number + first_Difference;
}
Difference(Sum first_Difference, Number first_number){
    s1 = first_Difference + first_number;
}
Difference(Sum first_Difference, Sum second_Difference){
    s1 = first_Difference + second_Difference;
}
Difference(Number first_number, Modulus first_modulus ){
    s1 = first_number + first_modulus;
}
Difference(Modulus first_modulus, Number first_number){
    s1 = first_number + first_ modulus;
}
Difference(Modulus first_modulus, Modulus second_modulus){
    s1 = first_modulus + second_modulus;
}
Difference(Sum first_Difference, Product first_difference){
    s1 = first_Difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Product first_difference, Sum first_Difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_Difference;
}
Difference(Sum first_Difference, Quotient first_difference){
    s1 = first_Difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Quotient first_difference, Sum first_Difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_Difference;
}
Difference(Sum first_Difference, Difference first_difference){
    s1 = first_Difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Difference first_difference, Sum first_Difference){
    s1 = first_Difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Sum first_Difference, Modulus first_modulus ){
    s1 = first_Difference + first_modulus;
}
Difference(Modulus first_modulus, Sum first_Difference){
    s1 = first_Difference + first_modulus;
}
Difference(Difference first_difference, Quotient first_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Quotient first_difference, Difference first_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Product first_difference, Quotient first_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Quotient first_difference, Product first_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Quotient first_difference, Modulus first_modulus){
    s1 = first_difference + first_modulus;
}
Difference(Modulus first_modulus, Quotient first_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_modulus;
}
Difference(Difference first_difference, Quotient first_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Quotient first_difference, Difference first_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_difference;
}
Difference(Difference first_difference, Modulus first_modulus){
    s1 = first_difference + first_modulus;
}
Difference(Modulus first_modulus, Difference first_difference){
    s1 = first_modulus + first_difference;
}
Difference(Difference first_difference, Modulus first_modulus){
    s1 = first_difference + first_modulus;
}
Difference(Modulus first_modulus, Difference first_difference){
    s1 = first_difference + first_modulus;
}
```

to make sure I have every possible combination of ways for my main class. Is there any way that I can make this more efficient? I am tired of having to write this over and over again.

Comment: How about a factory method that parses your calculation and returns an instance? That way you'd only need one private constructor. What you're doing now is pretty much the worst possible choice.

Comment: Doing things in the constructor is code smell; constructors should only initialize code. All those types, `Sum`, `Product`, etc., could feasibly be member methods of a single type. Also, it's weird that you calculate a sum in a constructor for `Difference` as the meanings are rather opposite. One possible approach is to have a `Calculation` class with a method that takes a lambda for the operation to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you can use the `+` operator in a user defined class, but a solution to your problem is to create an empty interface `IExample` and then implement it to all your classes and have one constructor:

```
Difference(IExample i1, IExample i2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So then how do I subtract the two types from each other?

Comment: You need to put the logic inside the IExample. For example have a function that returns a number, implement it and then call it in the Difference

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Product, Quotient, Difference, Sum, and Modulus all extend Number, you could just do:

```
Difference(Number firstNumber, Number secondNumber){
    s1 = firstNumber + secondNumber;
}
```

When an overloaded method or constructor is called, the most specific method/constructor is used.  Here's an example:

```
Sum s = new Sum(1);
Product p = new Product(2);
Difference d = new Difference(s, p);
```

The constructor with Number parameters will be called since there isn't a more specific constructor like *Difference(Sum firstSum, Product firstProduct)*.  Specifying more specific constructors like you did is optional (especially since all the constructors are doing the same thing).

Comment: No because when I do my main statement, I have to be able to do Difference d1 = Difference(Number(6.7), Number(5.9)) and get d1 has to equal 0.8

Comment: You'd need to do some kind of conversion to widen the result I think.  Kind of like how Java widens the result of a integer * double to a double.  Here's a link on type promotion rules: http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0020__Language-Basics/The_Type_Promotion_Rules.htm.  I still think you could handle this logic inside one constructor instead of having multiple constructors for all combinations of data types.

Comment: @LewBloch has a great comment above that makes sense.  You may want to change the design of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach, in outline:

package practice;

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Operation<T> {
  final T value;

  public Operation(T val) {
    this.value = val;
  }

  public Operation<T> op(T operand, BiFunction<T, T, T> func) {
    final Operation<T> result = new Operation(func.apply(value, operand));
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
      return true;
    }
    if (! (other instanceof Operation)) {
      return false;
    }
    Operation<T> otherOp = (Operation<T>) other;
    return (value == null ? otherOp.value == null : value.equals(otherOp.value));
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return value == null ? 0 : value.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Operation{ " + value + " }";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Operation<Integer> oper1 = new Operation<>(17);
    Operation<Integer> operMinus = oper1.op(23, (x, y) -> x - y);
    Operation<Integer> operPlus = oper1.op(23, (x, y) -> x + y);

    System.out.println("oper1 = " + oper1);
    System.out.println("operMinus = " + operMinus);
    System.out.println("operPlus = " + operPlus);
  }
}
```

You could use a variation of this approach with a `protected op` method, predefining locked-down operations based on it instead of letting the client provide the `func` argument.

Note that we do not commingle business logic with construction.

Answer (score 0):

Oh what I did was create a super class Expression and then could do

```
public class Sum extends Expression{
private Expression lhs;
private Expression rhs;

Difference(Expression e1,  Expression e2) {
            lhs = e1;
            rhs = e2;
}
}
```